# Processing input in the context before creating model, in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What I need to develop is a 'invite user to a context' application; in the input passed to the Context store method I have the context name and a list of users (email).

Here I need to create the context, and then, for each user:

1. If the user is registered (exists in the DB), attach him to the context (easy)
2. If the user does not exists, create a new User instance (with temp data), send the confirmation email to the user to invite him to register.

My question is that I'm not feeling comfortable doing all this login in the store method of the Context controller.

Where is the best place to do this?

Comment: You could fire an event using observers.

Comment: Yes, but I need the ID's of the new users, to register them. I'm not sure it can be asyncronous

Comment: You can pass the object when triggering the event, `Event::fire('user.mailer.confirmation', [$user])`.